# Embedding a navigation controller in a container - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

How to embed a Navigation controller in a container View?
When I place the container the first this that shows is a viewController embed to the container, I want to change that viewController to a navigation view and set it rootViewController and other views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just add the ViewController into a UINavigationController and set the UINavigationController as your rootViewController. Hope that helps:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = nvc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @3vangelos

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add navigation controller with storyboard then it's very simple, just follow these steps:
* select the storyboard to which you want to attach a storyboard,
*go to toolbar then,
* Editor->Embed In->Navigation controller.
*your storyboard automatically embedded with navigation controller.

Comment: Yes its a easy way to embedded navigation controller view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController controls the UIViewController . So the "container" is NavigationController not others.

The same as UITabbarController. If you want to change the view architecture even the rootViewControler. I will tell you my experience.

Like this:

[image]

We can switch the login page and homeTabbar container freedom.

```
if (Boolean conditions) {//show login page
    [self showLoginAndRegisterVC];
} else { //show home Page
    [self showHomeViewController];
}
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```